# Install a cross compiler in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ruby, windows, filesystems

I have a Ubuntu 13.04 system and want to install cross compiler to build the same source code to Windows platform (x86).
I don't know where to start.
Also, I need to set the path for cross compiler in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `fileutils` first-

Then use `rm_rf()` method -

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.rm_rf('your_directory_path/filename')
```

Check more options for the module -
 http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html

You can also use `rm_r()` for deletion.

Comment: Be *very* careful using `rm_rf` as it doesn't care where it descends into or what it deletes. Do NOT run it with administrator or root privileges unless you are VERY sure what you are doing. You can reduce a functioning machine to a doorstop in a second with a badly written `rm_rf`.